# Windows 7 Keeps Changing the MBR on boot

Tags: windows, linux, grub, mbr

I am having an issue with Windows 7 changing the boot order everytime I start up.

I have 4 partitions:

- boot
- linux
- windows.

Grub is installed on the boot, and boots up both operating systems fine, however when I boot to Windows the bootable partition is changed to Windows and the MBR is rewritten.

How do I stop this? Its rather annoying to have to boot, chroot and fix this problem everytime.

I also don't want to use the Windows boot select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the "makeactive" option in grub and apparently when Win7 sees that it is the active partition it latches on.

Answer (score 1):

Something is restoring the Windows boot sector to the MBR.  Could it be system restore, or anti-virus software?

Or could it be Adobe?

There was an article in "2006 - The Hacker Quarterly", describing a very similar issue, and this was caused by Adobe's latest software protection.  If this sounds likely then have a look for the article "Hey Adobe! Leave My Boot Loader Alone!", published in the Winter 2009-2010 edition. (I'll paste a URL link here if found).

Comment: have a look at http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/321444.html ... unless this is something new; i haven't found the 2600 article online to read.  that doesn't sound like the same situation tho; *that* symptom sounds like it would look like a broken Grub, not a working Win7 bootloader.

Comment: Grub works .... but everytime I boot to Win7 it changes the boot loader and the partition back to windows. I can't find an option in Windows to tell it not to do this, and its a new install.

Comment: Also the only adobe product i have installed is flash