# Windows 7 destroys my GRUB2 on every boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, grub, mbr

I have a dual boot setup with Ubuntu and Windows 7, I generally use Ubuntu but some times start Windows 7. Every time I have used Windows 7 my GRUB2 installation brakes and as soon as GRUB2 is launched the computer reboots and keeps doing this forever.

I then need to boot with live CD, chroot and reinstall GRUB2. This takes a lot of time is really annoying.

Obviously something in windows itself or some application in windows rewrites a part of the MBR. I can't understand that this is not considered a big security issue in windows since it completely takes out the computer so that none of the OS can boot.

Can I in some way write-protect the MBR in windows? Is there any type of software built in to windows or some anti-virus or similar that can do this?

Regardless of which application in windows that brakes the MBR there must be a general way of denying this applications write permissions to the MBR.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/149299/windows-7-keeps-changing-the-mbr-on-boot-grub2

http://superuser.com/questions/118510/windows-7-keeps-changing-the-mbr-on-boot

Comment: Thanks for the links, I have already read those questions and that is why I'm looking for a way to simply write protect the MBR, to prevent all these DELL utilities and others from writing to the hdd's MBR.

Answer (score 3):

If you have makeactive in you menu.lst entry for Windows try removing it to see if it helps.

Comment: I can't find and menu.lst file, I'm using GRUB2 and I think menu.lst is only used in GRUB.

Comment: Then it is grub.cfg which should be somewhere in /boot/grub/